# Why does Windows USB enumeration take so long (compared to Linux)

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint, kvm-switch

I have two computers at work, one Windows 7, the other Linux Mint. To easily switch between them I have a KVM. It is not one of the fancy ones which feeds the computers a generic USB device to keep everything enumerated, rather it actually physically switches devices (you can see devices lose power briefly).

Switching to the Linux device, it takes about 1-2 seconds before the keyboard and mouse become responsive. On Windows it take 9-10 seconds. Is there any reason Windows is so slow, and any way to speed it up?

(I have already tried turning off power saving on the USB controller, but this made no difference).

Comment: I have never waited 10 seconds for a keyboard to be responsive when connected to a Windows PC and KVM switch.  Something else is going on

Comment: I've seen this happen.  I *think* it's because Windows checks signatures on drivers for new devices as it's scanning INF files to find a driver, since 64-bit versions of Windows will only load signed drivers unless in test mode.  I haven't really looked into this, though.  It's probably related to some security GPO that would exist on domain-joined systems.

Comment: @LawrenceC
Do you know of a way to turn off the signature checking?

Answer (score 0):

Something triggered my USB flash drive to take a long time to come up in my Windows 7 laptop. Sometimes it enumerated quickly, at other times it took a full minute to start.

The fix in my case was to go to Device Manager and uninstall the USB Root Hub to where the flash drive was connected. This prompted my Windows 7 machine to restart. Next when I connected the USB flash, it reinstalled the driver and the flash started working normally again, immediately coming up each time I connect it.

[Edit]
After one day, it reverted to the way it was. So I'm not sure if the fixe worked after all, or at least it was short-lived.